# How to sum the last values of lists of elements that are included into a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary and i want to sum the last element of each list of every key and store it into a new variable (sum) .For example sum=3+6+9. I tried a dictionary comprehension but i only managed to get the sums of all lists. Is there a similar way or any other way to do this?

```
dic1={'data1': [1,2,3], 'data2': [4,5,6], 'data3': [7,8,9]}
```

Comment: I don't see a dictionary comprehension

Comment: Can you think of a way to get a list of the dictionary’s values? How about a list of their last values?

Comment: `sum(dic1[d][-1] for d in dic1)` -> `18`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the values with `dict.values()`, then sum the last values:

```
>>> sum(l[-1] for l in dic1.values())
18
>>> 3 + 6 + 9
18
```